# Java: observer-pattern notify in new thread

Tags: java, multithreading, observer-pattern

I have the following problem. Given a Interface EventNotifier for the Observer Pattern:

```
public interface EventNotifier {
    void newEvent(final String value);
}
```

A class, which implements this Interface, can register at another class, which calls *very often* the method newEvent. The Interface is given by a external library, so I cannot change it. Up to now I implemented it with an anonymous class:

```
Thread t = new Thread(new Runnable() {

    @Override    
    public void run() {

      watcher = new Watcher(new EventNotifier() {

          @Override
          public void newEvent(String value) {
              //do some stuff
              //will be called more than 20 times per second
          }
       });
 });
 t.start();
```

For better code readability I would like to expose this anonymous class into a new class, which extends Thread (because the handling should be parallel to other things).

How can I write a Thread, which does nothing (no endless-loop etc.), but wait for calling the newEvent method? The problem is, that newEvent will be called more than 20 times a second, so I cannot start a new thread for each call but the whole thing should be in a thread.

I hope you get the problem and somebody can help me.

Comment: In current design you have thread that registers your listener and then terminates, I think this is not what you want, isn't it? Do you want the calls to newEvent - "do some stuff" - to be processed in separate thread? Because now they are processed in the thread that runs the other component.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

What makes your post confusing is that the `EventNotifier` is in fact an observer/listener (it receives the event, it doesn't fire them), and the `Watcher` is in fact the notifier (it's the watcher that creates an event and calls the `newEvent` method).

I'll use the terms *observable* and *observer* from now on. The observable fires events, and thus calls the observer's newEvent method.

If you want the event handling to be done in a separate thread, use a `BlockingQueue`. Start a thread that loops endlessly, and tries to `take()` from the queue at each iteration. Register an observer to the observable, which simply takes the received event and `put()` it in the blocking queue.

Answer (score 2):

You can use [Executor](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/1.5.0/docs/api/java/util/concurrent/Executor.html) to avoid coding `BlockingQueue` and polling Thread by hand.

In your main class you will have something like:

```
Executor eventExecutor = Executors.newSingleThreadExecutor();
// ...
watcher = new Watcher(new EventNotifier() {
    public void newEvent(final String value) {
        eventExecutor.execute(new ConcurrentEventHandler(value));
    }   
});
```

And the concurrent event handler that performs handling in background thread:

```
class ConcurrentEventHandler implements EventNotifier, Runnable {
        private final String value;

        public ConcurrentEventHandler(String value) {
            this.value = value;
        }

        public void newEvent(final String value) {
            // do some stuff
        }

        public void run() {
            // executed in background thread
            newEvent(value);
        }
    }
```

I've implemented `EventNotifier` here but it isn't necessary of course

Answer (score 1):

Use plain old `wait/notifyAll`:

```
// we need final object to synchronize your code and library code on it
// it's convenient to make this object hold all needed data to be passed from library as well
// in your case AtomicBoolean should suffice (we can't use simple `final Boolean`, since it would be impossible to assign new value to it, as we need in code below).

final AtomicBoolean called = new AtomicBoolean(false);

EventNotifier en = new EventNotifier() {
          @Override
          public void newEvent(String value) {
               // this will be called by your external library
               synchronized(called) {
                    called.set(true); called.notifyAll();
               }
          }
       };

Thread t = new Thread(new Runnable() {
    @Override    
    public void run() {
         synchronized(called) {
            // wait here until library call occurs
            while (!called.get()) {
                 try {
                     called.wait();
                 } catch (InterruptedException e) {
                   // handle exception as desired
                 }
            }
            // reset called flag asap, so we will know when next call occurs
            called.set(false);
            ... // do your stuff
         }
    );
 });
t.start();
```

For general introduction to Java multi-threading programming, read [tutorial](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/essential/concurrency/index.html). Then, if topic is interesting to you, read "Java Concurrency in Practice" by Goetz.

In case, you need to process `value` passed into `newEvent` from library, you'll need some kind of `BlockingQueue` instead of simple `Boolean`.

Comment: are you sure that `final Boolean` flag can be modified?